# Is there a way to debug a cordova app using Android Studio and test it on different versions of Android?

Tags: android-studio, cordova

I really want to test my cordova app on different versions of Android to see if it fails on any.

Comment: it is the wrong place to ask this kind of question. Just google it

Answer (score 0):

Select avd manager from the configure section in android studio. From the Create Virtual Device section, you can create virtual devices in different devices and different android versions.

After creating devices, you can select and run your project from the top toolbar in android studio.